# Why is SqlException severity class different from what the spec says it should be?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, error-handling, azure-sql-database

I'm staring into logs of our service and see that there was a bunch of exceptions like this:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
Class 14
Number 40613
LineNumber 65536
Source .Net SqlClient Data Provider
```

> Database 'OurDatabase' on server 'ourserver' is not currently available.  Please retry the connection later.  If the problem persists, contact customer support, and provide them the session tracing ID of 'GUID-IN-HERE'.

Okay, we should retry... I open our retry logic code and clearly that code expects `Number 40613` with severity class set to 17. [Documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-develop-error-messages/) confirms that this error message should have severity class set to 17.

Why the difference? Is this a bug in the .NET Framework or what?

Comment: Looks like a case of User Generated Error - 40613, that's why the severity between 11 to 16, since 17 to 25 indicate software or hardware error, serious issues above 19

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.class(v=vs.110).aspx

May be same error number 40613 maps to range of severity levels internally

Comment: File a bug with the Azure team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention.  What you are seeing is due to a bug that's been exposed on V12.  The systems should report Severity = 17 (not 14) for error 40613.  We will fix this.

Please reach out to me if you have any questions.

Comment: Great to see someone from the azure sql team here!